# Post on user's friend wall with Facebook Dialog or PHP Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I am asking me if it's really possibe, in an application,
to post on a user's friend wall?

Explaination:

- User A allow my application with publish_stream permission.
- User A have 3 friends: B, C and D
- In my aplication I want to post a message in User C

User C don't use and authorize my app but is the friend of User A

I'm asking me if with feed dialog (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), or graph API, i can do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

publish_stream  Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends. With this permission, you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, without requiring offline_access. However, please note that Facebook recommends a user-initiated sharing model.

Taken from: [Facebook permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)

Comment: yes i know the permission documentation but i have tested this following stuff, and it's not working:

     FB.api('/123455/feed', 'post', opts, function(response)..

Comment: I receive the alert message 'Posting error occured" from this code: 
FB.api('/123456789/feed', 'post', opts, function(response) { if (!response || response.error)
        {
            alert('Posting error occured');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Success - Post ID: ' + response.id);
        }
    });

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can - if you use the feed dialog (FB.ui), the user can select a friends wall/timeline to post to.  You do not need the `publish_stream` permission for this as it is a user initiated post.  The `publish_stream` permission is only needed for "automatic" posts made by your application.

Comment: In fact, I need to do an automatic post from my app

I have the user's friend user_id and I want to publish on his wall, when my app want, a post on his wall